# Linq C# Sum in Group By

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to transform the SQL that is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1c8d/2 in linq below. The expected result is what is in sqlfiddle, but my LINQ returns more rows.

PS: In sqlfiddle the fields are reduced to not increase pollution and stay focused on my problem.

```
resultado.Dados =
    (
        from a in db.AgendaHorario
        join b in db.Agenda on a.AgendaID equals b.AgendaID                            
        select new 
        {
            a.AgendaID,
            Horario = a.Horario,
            Controle = a.Controle,
            Cor = b.Cor,
            Agenda = b.Sigla                            
        }).AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(g => new 
        {          
            g.AgendaID,
            Horario = g.Horario.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), 
            Data = g.Horario.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            g.Controle,
            g.Agenda,
            g.Cor
        })                        
        .Select(s => new
        {
            id = s.Key.AgendaID,
            title = s.Key.Agenda,                             
            start = s.Key.Data,                            
            color = String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Key.Cor) ? "3a87ad" : s.Key.Cor,
            className = "",
            someKey = 1,
            allDay = false,                            
            Resultado0 = s.Sum(m => m.Controle == "L" ? 1 : 0).ToString(),
            Resultado1 = s.Sum(m => m.Controle == "B" ? 1 : 0).ToString()                             
        });
```

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't look like your LINQ query. Are you sure you've posted the whole thing in the Fiddle?

Comment: Why on earth would you do your group by after the `.AsEnumerable`. Why on earth would you use `DateTime.ToString()` in your query and not your view layer? Consider using `EntityFunction.TruncateDate` if you are trying to get the Date part only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, this addresses the question of how to repeat your SqlFiddle in Linq. Note that the projection to a String Date cannot be converted to Sql directly, so I've had to early materialize with `AsEnumerable()` (obviously, in your real query, apply any filters prior to materializing!). You could probably do the grouping on just the date part using [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466188.aspx), e.g. 3 x applications of `SqlFunctions.DatePart` will allow you to group by dd, MM and YYYY

```
var dados = db.AgendaHorarios1
  .AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(ah => ah.Horario.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
  .Select(g => new {Horario = g.Key, 
                    Livre = g.Count(x => x.Controle == "L"),
                    Bloq = g.Count(x => x.Controle == "B"),
                    Aged = g.Count(x => x.Controle == "A")});
```

Comment: ... or if you have EF 6 then use `EntityFunction.TruncateDate` as per Aron's comment. Your mapping each row of L/A/B to 0 or 1 and then Summing is equivalent to Counting matches of values of `Controle`